# Problem with multiple fancyheader page styles

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I want to use multiple fancyheader styles in my document. I've run into a problem that seems to be a bug to me. The code below doesn't compile with `latex`; it seems stuck in an infinite loop.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancypagestyle{fancy}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyhead[C]{fancy \thepage}
  \fancyfoot{}
}

\fancypagestyle{tocstyle}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \fancyfoot[C]{\footnotesize{TOC \thepage}}
}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\pagestyle{tocstyle}

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\pagestyle{fancy}

\chapter{Intro}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

If I replace the fancyheader style `fancy` by anything else, e.g. `fancy1`, then everything does work as expected.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The package `fancyhdr` works essentially applying `\pagestyle{fancy}` everywhere (unless an already defined page style is declared). Thus, after

```
\fancypagestyle{foo}{...}
```

any declaration `\pagestyle{foo}` will really be translated into `\pagestyle{fancy}` with the values for the fields as stated in the previous definition of `foo`.

Therefore you *can't* say `\fancypagestyle{fancy}{...}`, but are free to use any other name you want, including those of other predefined styles.

I suggest you

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancypagestyle{main}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyhead[C]{fancy \thepage}
  \fancyfoot{}
}

\fancypagestyle{front}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \fancyfoot[C]{\footnotesize{TOC \thepage}}
}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\pagestyle{front}

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\pagestyle{main}

\chapter{Intro}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this clarifies the (to me) unexpected behaviour. I also found that when defining extra styles like this, switching back to `\pagestyle{fancy}` will use the settings of style `foo` last used, and not the default settings declared outside of any `\fancypagestyle{foo}`.

Comment: Thanks. This had me scratching my head for a while – it's not very clear in the documentation for `fancyhdr`.